# CI/CD release Angular:SSR Azure Devops

Tags: angular, azure, ci-cd, azure-pipelines

Наткнулся на очень распространенную ошибку. При накатывании релиза моего Angular app получаю ошибку

`##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.`

Поиски показали что данная ошибка фиксается скриптом Yaml файл вот такой строкой

`- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1`

Пробовал всеми вариациями, не помогло. Моя последняя версия yaml файла

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '14.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm outdated
    npm run build:ssr --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Как бы я не пытался я получаю все равно одну и туже ошибку, никак артифактов не собираю, просто хочу накатить на свой сервис web angular ssr

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась вот таким Yaml скриптом

```html
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm outdated
    npm run build:ssr --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'dist'
```